# Why is it that the MAC address of a remote host can be determined only if the scanning station sits at a mirrored port?

Tags: nmap, penetration-testing, network-security, port-scanning

I am going through my penetration testing course and just learned that the MAC address of a remote host can be determined only if i am either the admin of the network or when i am sitting at the mirrored port. I am wondering why can't it be retrieved from a packet at any random place in the network. I mean to ask what is the exact reason behind retrieval of MAC at the mirrored port that cant be done anywhere else in the network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pursuing a pen testing course without understanding fundamentals of network and software is a good idea. This question is ambiguous. When you say network admin, what capability of network admin you are talking about? When you say mirrored port, mirrored to what? remote host port? or a port in remote network?

I will still try to answer your question assuming that you want to find the MAC of remote host, provided that you know its IP. Generally ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) packets are used by hosts in a network to find MAC addresses of remote hosts. An ARP packet with destination MAC ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff is sent to all hosts asking who has that specific IP. You can simply issue below command:

```
arp -a <ip address of remote host>
```

This would give you MAC address of remote host.

Notice I have mentioned "in a network" because you have to be in the same network as remote host in order to send the packet with broadcast MAC address. A layer 2 broadcast packet cannot be sent across networks.